# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND deploying Azure Functions from Visual Studio Code

Tags: deployment, azure-functions

I've got a previous project that's been working fine. I'm converting an old project to use Azure Functions via [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp?pivots=programming-language-csharp) but I cannot deploy to the Function App without getting that error.

I tried making a brand new project, using all new app and resource names, and still...after everything is created, I get this vague error with no more details from the extension.

Any ideas how to solve this? It's literally blocking progress now...

Thanks!
-Matt

**EDIT* - My previous project is NOT working anymore either. It's been fine for months, now suddenly I get the same error. The error I get is:

**getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND**

There doesn't appear to be any other information when the error pops up.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide error details or screenshot

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question, I apologize. Ty

Answer (score 0):

There are likely many things that can cause this issue. For me, the solution was to flush my DNS locally on my Windows machine. I don't know why, but I've successfully deployed since then.